# Wait for child processes to exit splwow64 causing problems

Tags: c#, process, wait

I am writing an application that launches an external app then waits for it and all child processes to exit.

```
        private int RunCmdAndGetExitCode(string command, string args, ProcessWindowStyle windowStyle, WaitEnum wait)
    {
        Process scriptProc = new Process();
        scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = command;
        scriptProc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
        scriptProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = windowStyle;

        if (scriptProc.Start())
        {
            if (wait == WaitEnum.MainProcess)
            {
                scriptProc.WaitForExit();
                return scriptProc.ExitCode;
            }
            else if(wait == WaitEnum.None)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (wait == WaitEnum.ChildProcesses)
            {
                ProcessMonitorThread _procmon = new ProcessMonitorThread(this, scriptProc);

                while (ThreadCount != 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

`ProcessMonitorThread` is a class that inherits from `BackgroundWorker`

```
public class ProcessMonitorThread : BackgroundWorker
{
    private IChildCounter _Counter;
    private Process _processToMonitor;


    public ProcessMonitorThread(IChildCounter counter, Process processToMonitor)
    {
        _Counter = counter;
        _Counter.ThreadCount++;
        _processToMonitor = processToMonitor;

        this.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(ProcessMonitorThread_DoWork);
        this.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(ProcessMonitorThread_RunWorkerCompleted);
        this.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void ProcessMonitorThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _Counter.ThreadCount--;
    }

    void ProcessMonitorThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int processid = _processToMonitor.Id;

        _processToMonitor.WaitForExit();

        foreach (int _childid in GetChildProcessIDs(processid))
        {
            Process ps = Process.GetProcessById(_childid);

            new ProcessMonitorThread(_Counter, ps);
        }
    }
    List<Int32> GetChildProcessIDs(int ProcessID)
    {
        List<Int32> _ChildProcesses = new List<Int32>();

        // Use the ObjectQuery to get the list of configured printers
        System.Management.ObjectQuery oquery =
            new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ParentProcessId =" + ProcessID);

        System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mosearcher =
            new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(oquery);

        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection _AllChildProcesses = mosearcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject _cprocess in _AllChildProcesses)
        {
            Int32 _processid;
            _processid = Convert.ToInt32(_cprocess["ProcessId"]);
            _ChildProcesses.Add(_processid);
        }

        return _ChildProcesses;
    }
}
```

When I launch an app that can print it launches splwow64 and that process becomes one of the child processes.  The problem is that when I close the app I have launched splwow64 doesn't close with it and will wait for some kind of timeout. it is only when splwow64 terminates that my app reports that the app I launched and all of its child processes have terminated.  Which is correct.  However I don't really want to wait for splwow64.

Is there any way I can identify system processes or processes that could be left running after my process has terminated?

I know I could ignore processes with a name of splwow64 but that seems a bit of a workaround to me.

Comment: It is your own code that does this.  Why are you waiting for child processes at all?

Comment: Yes.  I have written an application that has a list of available apps.  The user can select one of these apps to launch.  When they do this my application reads the settings for that app and sets screen res, mounts an ISO and runs the app.  My app then waits for the app they selected (and any child processes) to exit.  My application then unmounts the ISO and resets the res.  Hence I need to wait.

Comment: I know that this is an oldie and this isn't technically an answer, hence the comment:  If this is a server that doesn't need to print, removing all printers (which may be just the default Microsoft XPS Document Writer) seems to cause splwow64.exe not to bother loading in the first place.  That's the solution I used for a similar problem, and it was by far the easiest fix.  Though I could see it being categorized as a "workaround".